# How do I replace an attribute using htmlParser?

Tags: java, html, parsing

UPDATE: Hi Pascal, Thanks for the quick reply, This is almost what I wanted. The newlink is different for each tag, can you please help me to do that.

All I need to do is iterate over all the link tags that appear in the input String, grab their value, and replace with a different link with out disturbing the link text

I am new using htmlParser in Java, please help me with this condition.

```
htmlString =  <a class="user" href="">first name</a> posted on <a class="user" href="">Test Test</a>'s wiki entry, <a href="http://localhost:8080/b/lll/ddd">werwrwrwerwerwer</a>, in
```

I need to replace the `href` link in `<a class="user" href="">` to another link in the tag.

Comment: You should try to format your question. Perhaps it's getting clearer then.

Comment: Do you mean this one? http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Try and replace all of the < and > characters with &gt; and &lt; 
As-is, your code sample is unreadable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) as HTML parser, you can do some transformations with [visitors](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/visitors/package-summary.html).

For example, you could create your own [NodeVisitor](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/visitors/NodeVisitor.html) to visit `a` tags:

```
public class MyLinkVisitor extends NodeVisitor {

    public MyLinkVisitor() { }

    public void visitTag(Tag tag) {
        if (tag.getTagName().equals("A")) {
            LinkTag link = (LinkTag) tag;
            link.setLink("http://newLink/"); //implement your logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Then, create a [Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Parser.html), parse the HTML string and visit the returned node list:

```
Parser parser = new Parser(htmlString);
NodeList nl = parser.parse(null);
nl.visitAllNodesWith(new MyLinkVisitor());
System.out.println(nl.toHtml());
```

This is just one way to do it.

Comment: Hi Pascal, 
          Thanks for the quick reply, This is almost what I wanted. The newlink is different for each tag, can you please help me to do that.

Thanks
Micheal

Comment: @Michael As I wrote in the line comment, you have to "implement your logic here". I can help you if you give me some hints on the logic but I can't guess what you want to do exactly. So please, clarify your needs.